# ReactNative: AsyncStorage Problem : I can't retrieve Data the correctly

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I am trying to use the AsyncStorage in my Project by Saving the token to the AsyncStorage by using `setItem()`

Action that response with token

```
 import axios from 'axios'; 
 import {URL, Config} from '../../service/Api';   
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export const checkSmsToLoginUser = value => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN_REQUEST'});
  try {
    const {data} = await axios.post(`${URL}user/checkSMSCode`, value, Config);
    console.log(data.token); // it consoles the token
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_TOKEN', data.token);
    dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: data?.token});
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN_ERROR', payload: error});
  }
};
```

and I dispatch the action in the component,  then I try to get the the token from the the AsyncStorage by using `getItem`

```
 const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN');
      return token, JSON.parse(token);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  };

  console.log(getData(), 'token From AsyncStorage');
```

but when I console the token that comes from the AsyncStorage, I have some sort of unhandled promise
[image]

any clue what's the problem or maybe solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
function App() {

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN');

      // Log here
      console.log(JSON.parse(token), 'token From AsyncStorage');

    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   getData(); // call here
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an async function without awaiting for it.

The code is correct, but the console log is not correct:

> console.log(getData(), 'token From AsyncStorage'); // missing async logic

Insert the console log inside the getData function, or await for the response.

Answer (score 0):

By Adding the `getData()` in `UseEffect` and handling the promise by using `then().catch()` worked for me

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res, 'it worked');
        setToken(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```